# Offset internal page #link by X pixels from top of page

Tags: jquery

I have a static top menu bar on my website, 50px in height. If someone were to directly visit this address:

```
http://example.com/page.html#somelink
```

The position is 50px too high as the menu is covering it up.

Is there any way to make it so that any links which end in `#something` will be offset by 50 pixels from the top?

Comment: Not sure your web site is hosted on example.com :-p . Probably not the link you really wanted to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did this by adding an empty anchor that via CSS is positioned absolute with a top that offsets the menu height.

This fiddle sort of shows it: http://jsfiddle.net/R67L5/

Markup:

```
<div class="spacer"></div>
<a name="heading" class="jump-to"></a>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<a href="#heading">Jump To Heading</a>
```

And CSS:

```
div.spacer {
    height: 70px;
}

a.jump-to[name] {
    position: absolute;
    top: -70px;
}
```